# How to open map activity with an existing position

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

I have a problem that I can not find the solution.
I have one map activity and one listview activity. in this listview activity i have put a list of items. the problem I can not find **how to order when this listview is clicked then the out is the map activity that I have created**. in the map activity there has been a marker with a position that has been fitted. **how to order that when listview is clicked then out the map activity with the appropriate position.**

**this is the coding I use**

Layer_Hotel.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Layer_Hotel extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrName);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    */


    ArrayList<Xiaomi> list = new ArrayList<Xiaomi>();
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Billiton Hotel & Klub", "Jl. Letda Zainudin Aba RT.01 RW.01 No.26"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Hotel Lux Melati", "Jl. Kedung Halang"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Grand Hatika Hotel", "Jl. Raya Sindangbarang"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Golden Tulip Essential Belitung", "Jl. Brigjen Saptaji Hadi Prawira"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("BW SUITE Belitung Hotel", "Jl. Veteran"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Bahamas Hotel & Resort", "Jl. KH. Soleh Iskandar"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("The Villa of Lor In Tanjung Tinggi", "Jl. RE Abdullah No. 16"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Hotel Santika Premiere Beach Resort Belitung", "Jl. Tentara Pelajar"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Arumdalu Private Resorts", "Jl. KH Sholeh iskandar"));
    list.add(new Xiaomi("Leebong Island Resort", "Jl. Raya Parakan Benda"));

    ListHotel adapter = new ListHotel(this, list);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0 : Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:-2.739872,107.632400?z=17");
                         Intent htl1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                         htl1.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                         startActivity(htl1);
                break;

                case 1 : Intent htl2 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl2);
                    break;

                case 2 : Intent htl3 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl3);
                    break;

                case 3 : Intent htl4 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl4);
                    break;

                case 4 : Intent htl5 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl5);
                    break;

                case 5 : Intent htl6 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl6);
                    break;

                case 6 : Intent htl7 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl7);
                    break;

                case 7 : Intent htl8 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl8);
                    break;

                case 8 : Intent htl9 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl9);
                    break;

                case 9 : Intent htl10 = new Intent(Layer_Hotel.this, BelitungMap.class);
                    startActivity(htl10);
                    break;

            }
            //Toast.makeText(Layer_Hotel.this, "PILIH",
            //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

BelitungMap.Java
*this is a map activity*

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Window;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.Map;

public class BelitungMap extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap map;

private LatLng hotel1 = new LatLng(-2.739872, 107.632400);
private LatLng hotel2 = new LatLng(-2.742191, 107.628693);
private LatLng hotel3 = new LatLng(-2.740410, 107.626108);
private LatLng hotel4 = new LatLng(-2.739044, 107.626762);
private LatLng hotel5 = new LatLng(-2.728040, 107.629075);
private LatLng hotel6 = new LatLng(-2.721031, 107.629697);
private LatLng hotel7 = new LatLng(-2.560926, 107.702065);
private LatLng hotel8 = new LatLng(-2.557391, 107.745207);
private LatLng hotel9 = new LatLng(-3.230771, 107.647814);
private LatLng hotel10 = new LatLng(-2.961165, 107.533155);




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.belitung_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;


    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel1)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Billiton Hotel & Klub").snippet("Hotel Bintang 3"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel2)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Hotel Lux Melati").snippet("Hotel Bintang"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel3)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Grand Hatika Hotel").snippet("Hotel Bintang 4"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel4)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Golden Tulip Essential Belitung").snippet("Hotel Bintang 3"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel5)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("BW SUITE Belitung Hotel").snippet("Hotel Bintang 4"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel6)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Bahamas Hotel & Resort").snippet("Hotel Bintang "));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel7)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("The Villa of Lor In Tanjung Tinggi").snippet("Hotel Bintang"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel8)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Hotel Santika Premiere Beach Resort Belitung").snippet("Hotel Bintang"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel9)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Arumdalu Private Resorts").snippet("Hotel Bintang"));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(hotel10)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinhotel))
            .title("Leebong Island Resort").snippet("Hotel Bintang"));


}
}
```

according to the coding I use. how to Layer_Hotel.Java can open BelitungMap.Java

On the listview I've created. first listview when clicked it will show google map application.
I think it's because `htl1.setPackage ("com.google.android.apps.maps");`
I do not know if it's true or not because that's the problem.

by the way sorry if the english is bad. I am from Indonesia using google translate.

Answer (score 0):

So if i understood what you want is when you click on item in your listview it opens map with the marker according to that element in your list , so here is how you can do it :

**first** you should create an **object** with this element :

```
String name; 
String adresse;
Double latitude;
Double longitude;
```

create your `constructor` and `geters` and `setters`

**second** , you should create `adapter` for your `ListView` using `ArrayList` of your 
created `object`

**Then** on your `getView` method in your `adapter` , use `view.setOnclickListenner()` create a new `Intent` and pass some extra to it , `intent.addExtra("PLACE_NAME",listOfYourObject.get(position).getname());`
 add all information you need adresse , latitude , longitude ...... and then call `startActivity(intent)`

**Finally** use `getIntent.getStringExtra("PLACE_NAME")` to get the name , and use `getIntent.getStringExtra()` and `getIntent.getDoubleExtra()` to get the other value needed .

Now that you have what you need create your marker with specefic position ,name and adresse !